# I need some help archiving an NSArray to hold some values and add/delete them later

Tags: ios, objective-c, archive, nscoding

I am doing an app as a starter to get some experience, I am making a simple app that stores assignments in a table view. So I have a table view as a main view and a plus button that pulls up a modal view controller that allows the user to enter information about the - class name, assignment title, assignment description, due date, and a switch to turn on/off notifications. These values are stored in a AssignmentInfo model. I need to be able to archive (NSCoding) these values, and add to them when new data is entered. Here is some sample code that might help give a better idea:

AssignmentInfo.h -

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *className;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *assignmentDescription;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *assignmentTitle;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *dateTimeString;
@property (nonatomic)bool notifcationStatus;
```

AddEditViewController.m -

```
{
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateTimePicker;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *procrastinationNotificationSwitch;
@property (nonatomic,strong)AssignmentInfo *assignmentInfo;
```

AddEditViewController.m -

```
- (IBAction)addTheInfo:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePicker.date];
    self.assignmentInfo.className = self.className.text;
    self.assignmentInfo.assignmentTitle = self.assignmentTitle.text;
    self.assignmentInfo.assignmentDescription = self.assignmentDescription.text;
    self.assignmentInfo.dateTimeString = dateTimeString;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.assignmentInfo.className);    

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: What do you mean you need to archive them, like, between app launches?

Comment: @powerj1984 yes exactly.

Comment: It looks like your modal view controller is calling dismissViewControllerAnimated? Likely you want to access its presenting view controller and dismiss the modal view. Also this is probably a good place to send your assignmentInfo object to that presenting view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll link a post from the inimitable NSHipster on the subject.
http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

> NSCoding is a simple protocol, with two methods: -initWithCoder: and
>   encodeWithCoder:. Classes that conform to NSCoding can be serialized
>   and deserialized into data that can be either be archived to disk or
>   distributed across a network.

```
@interface Book : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property NSString *title;
@property NSString *author;
@property NSUInteger pageCount;
@property NSSet *categories;
@property (getter = isAvailable) BOOL available;
@end

@implementation Book

#pragma mark - NSCoding

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
    self.author = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"author"];
    self.pageCount = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"pageCount"];
    self.categories = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"categories"];
    self.available = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"available"];

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.author forKey:@"author"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:self.pageCount forKey:@"pageCount"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.categories forKey:@"categories"];
    [encoder encodeBool:[self isAvailable] forKey:@"available"];
}

@end
```

Once your class is setup you can save/restore from disk easily:

```
// Archive
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:books toFile:@"/path/to/archive"];

// Unarchive
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/path/to/archive"];
```

So in your case you have a class like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *assignmentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *assignmentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dateTimeString;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL notifcationStatus;
```

So you'd end up with an initWithCoder method like:

```
#pragma mark - NSCoding

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.className = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"className"];
    self.assignmentDescription = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"assignmentDescription"];
    self.assignmentTitle = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"assignmentTitle"];
    self.dateTimeString = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dateTimeString"];
    self.notifcationStatus = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"notifcationStatus"];

    return self;
}
```

and an encodeWithCoder like:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.className forKey:@"className"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.assignmentDescription forKey:@"assignmentDescription"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:self.assignmentTitle forKey:@"assignmentTitle"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.dateTimeString forKey:@"dateTimeString"];
    [encoder encodeBool:self.notifcationStatus forKey:@"notifcationStatus"];
}
```

Now you should be able to just add your newly created objects to an NSMutableArray, and when necessary save that array to disk/load it from disk.

Comment: How do I do it so that it is an array of the items that the user enters.

Comment: The modal view controller you are displaying should have a property 'presentingViewController', you should be able to call a method on it to add the new assignment to a NSMutableArray within that class. It might be better to create a protocol and use the delegate pattern here though.

Comment: So do I need to archive the array too?

Comment: If you want to save the array of assignments between app launches you need to archive the array, yes. If you only want to archive one assignment you could do that.

Comment: So I wouldn't need to archive all the objects just the array? and how do I create an array to keep adding to it a list of things that display in a table view, and also can delete from it?